# Why autocompletion did not work?

Tags: bash, perl

When I try to autocomplete file name as next: `perl t/fi`<kbd>TAB</kbd>+<kbd>TAB</kbd>  *It work fine.*
But when I use `-d` option on command line. It does not:
`perl -d t/fi`<kbd>TAB</kbd>+<kbd>TAB</kbd>

What should I do to make it works?